# TD Ameritrade API auth

Tags: oauth-2.0, access-token

I am trying to request access token for my API app, but the response is:

> "error=invalid_client&error_description=invalid_client".

My URL is:
https://auth.tdameritrade.com/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://mywebsite/stock&client_id=ar9S************xjWl@AMER.OAUTHAP

I know for sure that my `client_id` is correct since I can get a simple API for Stocks. Is this having to do with my account that needs to be transferred to Charles Schwebs?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. The redirect uri was not correct